# Failing at npm start

Tags: node.js, express, npm, npm-start

[image: error image with js and json file]

I am trying to run my index.js through nodemon start, but don't know why and where it is failing.

Comment: It seems a problem in your package.json file. Have you changed anything there?

Comment: no. it was working fine with node index.js

Comment: no. You miss a `,` at the end of line 7 of your package.json. If that doesn't solve your error, consider editing your question with your package.json, index.js and error trace in as code

Answer (score 1):

Your json is wrong you need to add "," after the test

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1", <-- ADD COMMA HERE
  "start": "nodemon index.js"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **npm init package-json** for making package.json

```
$ npm start
```

[image: package.json]
[image: index.json]
[image: terminal]